# How to pass a random key-value-pair to a function/constructor in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have this dict

```
cards = {
    'A': 1,
    '2': 2,
    '3': 3,
    '4': 4,
    '5': 5,
    '6': 6,
    '7': 7,
    '8': 8,
    '9': 9,
    '10': 10,
    'J': 10,
    'Q': 10,
    'K': 10
}
```

And this class

```
class Dealer:

    def __init__(self, hand1, hand2):
        self.hand1 = hand1
        self.hand2 = hand2
```

And I want to pass a random key-value pair to the constructor.
I have no idea how...
I tried this

`dealer = Dealer(cards, cards)` but it will pass the whole dict.

I also tried this

`dealer = Dealer(cards[random.choice(list(cards.keys()))], cards[random.choice(list(cards.keys()))])`

and could get a random Value but I want a key-value pair or at least just pass they key?

Comment: `random.choice(list(cards.items()))`

Comment: `Dealer(*random.choice(list(cards.items())))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Get a key from your dictionary and then use it to look up it's corresponding value. Like this:

```
import random

adict = {"1":"4","2":"5"}

k = random.choice(list(adict.keys()))
pair = (k, adict[k])

print(pair)
# output: ('1','4')
```